# Calling methods in one c++ program from another (Inter Process Communication)

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I would like to call methods from one of my c++ programs from another. These methods would have objects that I would pass back and forth.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

It is pretty complex data back and forth. One possible way I was thinking would be to create a web service, but I was hoping there could be something easier. Perhaps with COM or something?

This is for Windows only.

Comment: Processes (in other words running programs) don't typically allow for data (or code) to be shared between them. What exactly does these objects contain, and how much data, how often is it passed, etc?

Comment: The search term you're looking for is "inter-process communication" (or IPC).  Wikipedia has a good high-level overview of various methods used to accomplish this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Comment: Is RPC what are you looking for? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call)

Comment: While you are reading, also search the internet for "shared memory multiple proceses".

Comment: The *easiest* method to share data between processes is to use files. It may not be the fastest or most robust, but it is easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since u mentioned COM, I'm assuming you're working in windows.

You can use SendMessage function, and use WM_COPYDATA message.

Use it like this:

```
COPYDATASTRUCT *cds = new COPYDATASTRUCT;

//init cds
...

SendMessage(hwnd_receiver, WM_COPYDATA, hwnd_sender, cds);
```

To get hwnd of other application use EnumWindows and GetModuleFileName. Or you can use different mechanism, it's up to you.

Comment: One potential (barely documented) caveat to keep in mind is that UIPI can block WM_COPYDATA messages depending on the permissions of the processes.